# Windows Task Scheduler Scan Result 0x2 - a new solution?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-defender

I'm trying to schedule a daily Windows Defender scan on my Windows 10 PC using Task Scheduler but it always fails with a 0x2.   By itself that's old news -  the problem has been around for years and is VERY widely reported and while countless suggestions have been made for workarounds they typically don't work or they stop working after a day or two.  I'm doing manual scans but I want to automate them.

But I just did a Google search and noticed that there were zillions of reports of this problem in 2016-2018 but few in any in the last year (today is August 2021).  This suggested that maybe a recent solution has been found.    My PC is new in December 2020 and Windows Update says I'm up-to-date, so if there was a fix it's not on my PC.  Does anyone know if a new solution to this has emerged?

Comment: Windows Defender runs itself. There is not any need to schedule it. It has been running automatically on my Windows 10 computer for 4 years now. It does quick scans daily of all the important things.

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32>NET HELPMSG 2`
returns `The system cannot find the file specified.`. So your command is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean it runs itself?   I run full scans, which take a long time and tie up the drive, not quick scans, and I run them daily at night before I leave my studio (where the computer is).    How would Windows defender run a full scan on its own?

Comment: @ user1292580    What commend are you talking about?    I'm not running a command - Windows Task Scheduler does not require a hand-written command.       As I said in the OP, I'm using Task Scheduler.